# Хранения данных для подключения

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, безопасность

Имеется приватный репозиторий с проектом на гите, хочу сделать открытым. В коде имеются данные для подключения к бд (сама по себе база ничего ценного не содержит, однако, интересно на будущее). Где лучше всего и как хранить это? Проект на C#, WPF.

Comment: По идее скрыть это не получится, да и не надо наверное. Используйте дополнительные конфигурационные файлы, которые не будете пушить. Или переменные окружения например.

Comment: [Секреты приложения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets).

Comment: Если у вас приложение для предприятия, то проще всего использовать вход в БД с доменной учёткой: `Integrated Security=True`